# Drop default column added in dataframe Pn

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have this current output on my DataFrame:

```
     x_1   x_2     x_3     x_4        x_5    ID
0     159   xyz  883nne2  28h93  xx_lightz    10
1     159   xyz  883nne2  28h93  xx_lightz    10
```

I've been researching and I can't find the name of the most left column(without a column name) that is generated by default when a df is created. What is the name of this and how is it dropped?

The expected outcome should be:

```
x_1   x_2     x_3     x_4        x_5    ID
159   xyz  883nne2  28h93  xx_lightz    10
159   xyz  883nne2  28h93  xx_lightz    10
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add to the first answer: the "column" is not a column but an index. Every DataFrame *must* have an index. If you do not like the default index, you can designate any existing column to be the new index with `df.set_index(column_name)` but you cannot remove it for good.

You can suppress index generation in a CSV file with `df.to_csv(filename, index=False)`.

Answer (score 1):

The reason there is the `index`, not the columns , let us check

```
df.columns
Out[100]: Index(['x_1', 'x_2', 'x_3', 'x_4', 'x_5', 'ID'], dtype='object')
```

If only need `print`

```
print(df.to_string(index=False))
 x_1  x_2      x_3    x_4        x_5  ID
 159  xyz  883nne2  28h93  xx_lightz  10
 159  xyz  883nne2  28h93  xx_lightz  10
```

Comment: How do I go about removing it?

Comment: @Aldo you can not remove it , it is defaulted , but we can print it without it